# How to send values from api after maping react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using react hooks and i trying to send the value to function delete and to do function put

```
           <Fab aria-label="delete"
                      className={classes.fab}
                      value={vacation.id}
                      key={vacation.id}
                      onChange={setDeleteid(vacation.id)}
                      onClick={DeleteCard}>
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </Fab>
```

this is the function

```
  const DeleteCard = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

console.log('delete' + deleteid);
alert(deleteid)
const confirm = window.confirm(`You are sure you want to delete vacation number ?`);
if (confirm == true) {
await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/users/admin/delete/:${e}`)
} else {
  alert("You pressed Cancel!")
}
```

}

this is the my state

```
     //vacation
  const [vacation, setVacation] = useState([]);
  const [deleteid, setDeleteid] = useState();
  //putcard
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [destination, setDestination] = useState("");
  const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState("");
  const [toDate, setToDate] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
```

**Apparently the id I'm trying to send to state doesn't come in because it records me undifind**

---

**UPDATE**

This is my state

```
const [deleteid, setDeleteid] = useState('');
```

Here I want to send and it gives me undefined

```
  onChange={() => setDeleteid(value)}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're executing the function as the DOM renders (it runs the function once). To fix this, change your onChange event to an arrow function that calls your function, like this:

```
onChange={() => setDeleteid(vacation.id)}
```

This should do the trick, happy coding!

Comment: Yes I did that already but then he gives me the next problem >>>Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: why are you using e instead of e.target.value ? Also, you must bind the value to something that you can set with the input, otherwise you wont be able to change it (change the value to setDeleteId state)

Comment: No it doesn't help